# Bootstrap-select validation error placement

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-select

I am using the [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin, and HTML5 validation to validate the `<select>`.

When the form is submitted without selecting the option, I am able to view the error message. However, the error message is displayed outside the form and not next to the `<select>`.

This validation is working perfectly fine for other input fields that do not use the plugin, but has issues for any `<select>` that uses the plugin.

[image: Error displayed outside the form]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add html and css code to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that bootstrap-select will hide your original input and instead style it's own with divs  Here's what that looks like:

[image: boostrap-select DOM]

So when you submit, you should see the following error when HTML5 Validation tries to focus on your hidden control:

[image: not focusable]

According to the specs on [hidden input elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#hidden-state-(type=hidden))

> When an input element's type attribute is in the Hidden state [...] The input element represents a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user.

As a workaround, you can toggle the visibility back on, but collapse the control.  This might cause other issues, and wouldn't actually focus the right control, but would cause the validation message to appear in the right place.

You could use the following CSS

```css
select.selectpicker {
  display: block !important;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 34px;
  width: 0;
  border: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  box-shadow: none; 
  color: white; 
}
```

Also, you'll want a way to transfer focus events from the original, now available, control to bootstrap-select.  This will capture both your own tab events on the forum and help redirect focus when HTML5 validation kick in.

```js
$("select.selectpicker").focus(function(){
  $(this).next(".bootstrap-select").find('.selectpicker').focus();
});
```

**Here's a demo in stack snippets**:

```js
$("select.selectpicker").focus(function(){
  $(this).next(".bootstrap-select").find('.selectpicker').focus();
});
```

```css
select.selectpicker {
  display: block !important;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden; 
  
  height: 34px;
  width: 0;
  border: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  
  box-shadow: none; 
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>


<form >
  <input type="text" name="name" required /><br/>
  
  <select name="select-plain" required>
    <option></option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select><br/>
  
  <select name="select-boot" class="selectpicker" required>
    <option></option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select><br/>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. Your answer helped me understand the reason behind the issue and I was able to successfully overcome the problem. I took your css code ahead and worked with a few more properties to get what I wanted. So here's what I re-wrote. This may help someone else too - 

`select.selectpicker {
    display: inline !important;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border:0px;
    box-shadow:none;
    color:white;
    padding:0.5px;
    overflow:hidden; 
  }`

Comment: @Sasmit, good suggestions.  I also added the ability to transfer focus from the original control to the new one.  For best placement of the HTML5 validation message, it was better if the control had zero width, but the same height as bootstrap-select so that the tooltip didn't obscure the field.

Answer (score 0):

if you are setting bootstrap select from jquery use **select.bs-select-hidden** class to set the style.

In my case:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control select-tag" name="category" required>
       <option disabled selected >activities</option>
       <option value="swimming">Swimming</option>
       <option value="painting">Painting</option>
       <option value="music">Music</option>
       <option value="dance">Dance</option>
       <option value="computers">Computers</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
select.bs-select-hidden {
  border: 0 none;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block !important;
  height: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}
```